# What does "Fits" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ... On the way, Harry filled Ron in on everything Sirius had told him about Karkaroff. Though shocked at first to hear that Karkaroff had been a Death Eater, by the time they entered the Owlery Ron was saying that they ought to have suspected it all along.
>
> “**Fits**, doesn't it?” he said. “Remember what Malfoy said on the train,
>   about his dad being friends with Karkaroff? Now we know where they
>   knew each other. They were probably running around in masks together
>   at the World Cup.…

I figure "**fits**" here means something like: "it fits for the situation" or "that makes sense". But I don't know if my understanding is correct? Is it short for something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"fits", in this context, indeed means "makes sense".

> be compatible or in agreement with; match.
>
> *(from Google)*

The question, "Fits, doesn't it?", is trying to convey the idea that what they know about Karkaroff indeed matches the situation and there is **no contradiction**.

Answer (score 6):

> “Fits, doesn't it?”

To expand this to the full sentence the word "fits" is expressing everything below that is in bold

**All the information we have and everybody's actions all make sense**, doesn't it?

I hope you do jigsaws as this analogy will work a lot better if you do :)

Imagine the story to be a jigsaw, all the clues are jigsaw pieces, You have lots of pieces, some are together making a picture, but there are some gaps still.  This new piece fits nicely into one of the gaps filling in more of the picture.

Thanks to @AC for reminding me of this.

Comment: That's a very interesting way to look at it! Thanks!

Comment: I think mentioning puzzle pieces really helps this answer to explain the sense of OP's quote.  I would, however, argue that when "something fits" it's not necessarily the **last** piece of the puzzle.  It's just one more piece, and that piece fits nicely with the other pieces (as opposed to something which doesn't fit, which would be a bit of information that contradicts other facts/assumptions).  We have other, related expressions for "the **final** piece of the puzzle" (or "the missing piece") and when "all the pieces come together" or when they fall or fit into place.

Comment: @AC yes I agree with you, will edit to say that

Answer (score 5):

It is elliptical:

> [It] fits, doesn't it?

It means "to jibe, to agree".

For the ellipsis compare:

> We should paint the ceiling first and then the walls. That way we won't splatter the walls with ceiling paint.
>   -- Makes sense.

Such ellipsis is very common in informal conversation.

> We painted the room.
>   -- Looks good!